# Grouping the average days it takes to ship based on different shipping modes (SQL)

Tags: sql, average

Hoping someone can help me out with as I continue to learn SQL.

I have a dataset that include 3 different shipping modes (Regular Air, Express Air, and Delivery Truck)

I am looking to discover the average amount of days it takes products to ship based on the shipping mode being used.

I have calculated the days taken to ship, but I need help with grouping together the 3 different modes and then finding the average.

Much thanks

[what I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qo2IA.png)

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2019

Comment: Please see some tips on how to improve your question - [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) and how to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
and [what is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/)
and how not to use [pictures](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data, code or errors

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please add codes as text in the questins/answeres plese read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).
Aslo Stackoverflow editor now has a feature that allows you to use tables. see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support)

Answer (score 1):

You need to take what you have so far and do an aggregation on it:

```
SELECT   [Ship Mode],
         AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY,[Order Date],[Ship date]))
FROM     dbo.customerdata
GROUP BY [Ship Mode]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was definitely overcomplicating that